# Excel VBA dynamic Indirect

Tags: excel, vba, excel-indirect

I have a formula that uses:

```
=VLOOKUP($D18,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",Lookups!$B$38,"Item Reference'!$A:$G")),5,FALSE)
```

OR:

```
=vlookup(“Abc123”, in another workbook(by concatenating (path&Sheet&range)5,false)
```

There are 80 rows that have this formula (in the cells) with a one row iteration.  There are 105 columns that have similar formulas.

Each column has a different VLookup to

1. Either a different WkB
2. Same WkB/Different sheet or range with different criteria.

I need to automate this in VBA to remove the formulas within EVERY cell, and put in VBA, and only send the formula results to the appropriate cell.

Right now I have a VBA For/Next that does the VLookup and returns the value to the original file/proper cell.  With 80 rows, this takes about 9 seconds.  Take that * 105 columns…  * 52 sheets & it takes ,53 days.

My question is: can I use an array dump to do this instead of a For/Next???

Comment: I'm pretty sure a native [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) wouldn't take that long for 80 rows. Why not use the original native worksheet formula(s) and then `.Value = .Value` on the range?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have so far.

Comment: Also, Indirect is a [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) function, so it gets recalculated every single time anything changes on your worksheet. So don't forget to turn off calculation before running any macro. Or doing anything in this workbook.